# Jquery .bind events triggered when event capture or event bubble

Tags: jquery

All, I know in the Dom level 2 event model, there exists event capture and event bubble. but I just can't figure out how jquery deal with them.
So I did some experiment with the `.bind` method.
here is my code .please review it .

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('*').each(function(){
            var current = this;
            $(this).bind("dblclick",function(event){console.log('Capture for ' + current.tagName + '#'+ current.id +
                    ' target is ' + event.target.id);});

        });
    });
</script>
<body id="greatgrandpa">
    <div id="grandpa">
        <div id="pops">
            <img id="example" src="designer/templates/thumbnails/2ColsTemplate.PNG" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

the output looks like below

```
Capture for IMG#example target is example
Capture for DIV#pops target is example
Capture for DIV#grandpa target is example
Capture for BODY#greatgrandpa target is example
Capture for HTML# target is example
```

When I use the `event.stopPropagation();` the event handler will stop bubble the `dblclick` event.

But I have 2 questions for it . 
According the logs writing order ,I guessed the `bind` method make the event to be triggered in the event bubble(from bottom to the top of dom) not in the event capature(from top of the dom to the bottom). 
Another question is is there any possibility make the event to be triggered in the event capture period? thanks.

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery only supports the event bubbling phase, not the event capture phase, not least because for a long time, IE didn't support capture. What your code is showing you is *bubbling*, not *capturing*.

Capture goes from the `document` down to the element on which the event occurred; then bubbling starts on the element and bubbles up to the `document` again, which is why you see the events in the order you've shown (which is the bubbling phase).

Comment: Yes , As we can see in the logs . it is bubbing . from the bottom to the top .thanks.

Comment: ok . I got it . jquery only supports the event bubbling .thanks your good answer .

Comment: [IE9 and above support event capturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener#Browser_Compatibility).

Comment: @Barney: Hence the "for a long time" above.

Comment: Not a correction: just a clarification. The information might be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct. However there is a simple workaround. To get the same effective result you can stop propagation to end bubbling the event up, trigger the event on the parent of the target and then execute your desired code so that it will occur following the events on the parent objects.

for your example if you want effectively invert the execution of the handlers:

```
    $('*').each(function(){
        var current = this;
        $(this).bind("dblclick",function(event){

               // stop the event propagation
               event.stopPropagation();

               // execute allow the event to be executed on parent objects
               var parent = $(event.target).parent(); 
               if(parent) {  
                   parent.dblclick(); 
               }


               console.log('Capture for ' + current.tagName + '#'+ current.id +
                ' target is ' + event.target.id);});

    });
```

One downside to this methodology is if there a parent element has been defined to with a capture event handler, the capture will have already occurred and calling the event on the parent will cause the capture handler to re-execute. So this should only be used when you are aware of or control the events declared on all parents elements to the target.